# Auto click a link/button in webbrowser?

Tags: .net, browser

Theres a link i want to click. I also have the HtmlElement of the link. However it is /site/blah/# so i know theres some JS there. How do i simulate the click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

childElement.RaiseEvent("OnClick");

Answer (score 2):

All DOM elements have a click() method - have you tried calling that?

Comment: all i see is an event which i cant call.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just call the click() method

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    element = document.getElementById('thelinkid'); //or whatever other method you used to get the element
    element.click();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the prettiest but this has worked best for me:

webbrowser1.Navigate("javascript:document.forms[0].submit()")

Similarly you can fill out forms, remove elements, etc.